# How do I get rid of the commas when I try to output an array

Tags: javascript, html

I'm trying to output strings in an array as a sentence and in between the words it outputs the comma that's used to separate the strings and its so annoying.

```
let words = document.getElementById("Words");
let wordAr = ["This" , "is" , "a" , "test"];
let textIn = document.getElementById("Input");
let timer = 0;
let WPM = 0;
let text = document.getElementById("text");

words.innerHTML = wordAr.slice(0,4);

window.addEventListener("keydown", function(key){
    if(key.keyCode == 32){
        for (let i=0; i < wordAr.length; i++){
            WPM++;
        };
        console.log("test");
    };
});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can `join()` using spaces.

```js
let wordAr = ["This" , "is" , "a" , "test"];
console.log(wordAr.join(' '))
```

Comment: Can you show me how to insert that into the code `words.innerHTML = wordAr.slice(0,4);`

Comment: `.slice()` returns an array, so just join on it i.e `words.innerHTML = wordAr.slice(0,4).join(' ');`